# Inserting elements into new array and then deleting from old array, some elements getting ignored

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to remove pairs of the smallest and largest elements from an `Array` and store them in a second one. Is there a better way to do this or a Ruby method I don't know about that could accomplish something like this?

Here's my code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
pairs = []; for n in nums
  pairs << [n, nums.last]
  nums.delete nums.last
  nums.delete n
end
```

Current result:

```
nums
#=> [2, 4]
pairs
#=> [[1, 6], [3, 5]]
```

Expected result:

```
nums
#=> []
pairs
#=> [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: A good general principle is to not modify a collection that you are iterating over.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! One more thing: why exactly is it bad to do so and I'm still not entirely sure why certain numbers were getting skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `nums` is sorted and can be modified, I like this way because it has a mechanical feel about it:

```
pairs = (nums.size/2).times.map { [nums.shift, nums.pop] }
  #=> [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]] 
nums
  #=> []
```

I see @Drenmi has the same idea of using `shift` and `pop`.

If you don't want to modify `nums`, you could of course operate on a copy.

Comment: I like your code and as OP wants it clear the original array too, so please update your answer that showing `nums` as empty array so OP understood what happened at the end. 1+

Comment: @Gagan, thanks. Does my edit address you point? I'm a little confused because I don't know if Ethan's "output" is the wrong answer he's getting or his desired result. I've assume it's the former.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I originally interpreted it as the desired output (with some typos), but after running his code, I realized this is what his code generates. I included both situations in my answer, but you beat me to this one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I changed my answer to give a different option, and avoid the pitfalls of modifying and iterating at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating over an `Array` while deleting it's content is generally not advisible. Here's an alternative solution:

```
nums = *(1..6)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

pairs = []
#=> []

until nums.size < 2 do
  pairs << [nums.shift, nums.pop]
end

pairs
#=> [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `nums` to be empty at the end.